# Changing GtkText input method

Tags: c, windows, gtk, locale, gtk3

Due to a locale discrepancies, `"` and `'` symbols are displayed as `¨` and `´` in gtk-based text editors.

---

To fix that in my own Gtk3 application I used `GdkEventKey` to detect whether the user presses these buttons and if so then put the proper character directly. I still need to find way to not allow these old symbols to be printed and for that I could change input method to `None` from the text editor.

---

How can I change the input method to `None` within the source file of my project?

Answer (score 0):

You need a configuration file which will read something like this :
`quote='
doubleq="`

The easiest method is to load this between the times of gtk_init and gtk_main set global variables like key_quote from zero to the value loaded from the config file should they exist. At the corresponding point in your program which you're using gdkkey events just have an if statement something like

```
if(key_quote&&pressed==GDK_KEY_QUOTE)
```